# Get list of comments having voted as useful comment

Tags: support, comments, comment-badges

I just wonder if there is any way to find the statistics for comments that have been voted on as useful comments.

As there are some badges which are awarded on the basis of the number of useful comments. How would I see how many comments are awarded with how many votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a query for that on the data explorer here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution

It will give you a graph of your comment scores.

For example, here's mine right now:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Putting the URL

```
api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1041642/comments?sort=votes&min=5
```

in your browser will return a list of your votes with a least 5 upvotes. `1041642` is your *user id* on *Stack Overflow*